# Can you explain why there's a lot of TCP connections openned when running multiple requests?

Tags: python, http, curl, tcp

I try to understand why there's a lot of openned TCP connection when I running a lot of synchronous requests.

In Windows, I use Python 3 to open a HTTP test server in a console:

```sh
python -m http.server 9000
```

In a Git Bash console, I launch a lot of requests with a loop:

```sh
for i in $(seq 1000); do curl http://localhost:9000/; done
```

During the requests, I see a lot of TCP connections related to the curl client and the Python server. The number of openned TCP connections increases over time as you can see in the screenshot.
After some times, connections are closed.

[Screenshot of Windows Ressource Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGe5S.png)

Why the connections are still opened ?

**Edit 1:**

With one curl command, I can see a openned connection during 2 minutes with `netstat -n | grep :9000`:

```
  TCP    127.0.0.1:64301        127.0.0.1:9000         TIME_WAIT
```

Changing the TTL does not change the duration of the openned request.

Comment: Because you need one connection per request if they are all concurrent.

Comment: Windows has a default TTL time of 128 seconds: https://subinsb.com/default-device-ttl-values/

I'm not sure if that's the cause though, I'm no network engineer.

Comment: it's probably just the Resource Monitor lagging (perhaps intentionally lagging for debugging purposes, making short-lived connections visible?). still, can you check what happens if you use ```for i in $(seq 1000); do curl -H "Connection: close" http://localhost:9000/; done```   instead?

Comment: check it in Process Explorer, are the connections in CLOSE_WAIT state? in which case, it's just Python lagging in closing the connection handles on the server-side (thanks to Bagder/Stenberg for that one)

Comment: Are you really asking for the meaning of the TIME_WAIT state? Plenty of answers here about that.

Comment: @hanshenrik : the connection header does not change the result. With netstat, the status is `TIME_WAIT` during 2 mintues (see my edit).

Comment: This is exactly as expected and specified in RFC 793. What's your question?